# Populate Datagrid in WPF User Control

Tags: wpf, datagrid, user-controls

I'm crazy with a very simple Datagrid population via DataContext property (binding a DataTable) in a WPF User Control. I trasnport the code from User Control Project to a WPF Windows Project and it works fine. What happens? Bellow the code that works in WPF Window and dont works in WPF User Control:

XAML:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="true" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="282" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="datGrdFalhas" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="494" FontWeight="Normal" IsReadOnly="True" FontSize="14" TabIndex="211" />
```

Code:
...

```
        DataTable datTblFalhas = new DataTable();
        datTblFalhas.Columns.Add("Alarme",
                                 typeof(string)
                                );
        datTblFalhas.Columns.Add("Momento",
                                 typeof(string)
                                );

        DataRow datRowAlarme = datTblFalhas.NewRow();
        datRowAlarme[0] = "a";
        datRowAlarme[1] = "b";
        datTblFalhas.Rows.Add(datRowAlarme);

        datGrdFalhas.DataContext = datTblFalhas;
```

...

Thanks,

Comment: Its works fine for me. Directly in a window and in UserControl in window. Maybe your problem is not related? How do you put the userControl?

Comment: Are you sure this code runs in the UserControl?

Comment: Thanks for anwers. The User Control is almost a Windows projet, with charts, combos, textbox, etc. Yes, I run this code in WPF Windows Project that accommodates the User Control with sucess. I search in web and found something about User Contro Project configuration for binding, but nothing that works. Follow Initial WPF declarations in post:

Comment: I can post in 8 hours, but the User control have other bindins commands with sucess (listboxes, charts e comboboxes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well friends, after too much tests, I discovered the very, very stupid error: In a method to clean the datagrid (called in tabitem show), I put the command:

```
    datGrdFalhas.ItemsSource = null;
```

and not

```
    datGrdFalhas.DataContext = null;
```

cleaning the {Binding} action writed in WPF.

Now works fine. Thanks very much for attention and answers, and sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

```
<UserControl x:Class="ProMaqWPFLib.UsrCtrGestaoProducao" Name="usrCtrGestao"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
         xmlns:comCtrls="clr-namespace:ComControlsLib;assembly=ComControlsLib"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="388" d:DesignWidth="1339" Loaded="usrCtrGestao_Loaded">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Visibility x:Key="VisibilidadeSerieEntradaDispParada"/>
    <Visibility x:Key="VisibilidadeSerieSaidaEficiencia"/>
    <Visibility x:Key="VisibilidadeSerieRefugoQualidade"/>
    <Visibility x:Key="VisibilidadeSerieOEE"/>
    <Visibility x:Key="VisibilidadeSeriePareto"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Height="Auto" Name="grid1" Width="Auto">
     ...
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I did that. In next step, the datacontext datagrid is binding with datatable (observable in watch or on mouse over), but don't show data. Very weird... Thanks agains.